# Blend obj file import to the WPF project

Tags: wpf

I have got a problem, generated obj and mtl file with Blend. I imported into the project, but can't insert to the XAML file. Drag and drop not work, and Insert menu is missing. Anyone idea?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No just, haven't got insert menu, and if I drag and drop the obj file into the xaml nothing happen. But the obj file seems to be OK because if I open it, it will be display

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2013's BLEND version you can find the insert command in the context menu. In 2015 it is missing. I'm trying to find a workaround, but until then you can use the 2013 version.

> 1. In the Projects panel, right-click the name of your project, and then click Add Existing Item or Link to Existing Item.
> 2. Browse to the location of the 3D content (.obj file) that you want to import and any supporting materials (.mtl files and the image files that are used in the .mtl files), select all of the files at the same time (hold the Ctrl key while selecting the files), and then click Open.
>
> The 3D object data is now available to your project.
>
> In the Projects panel, right-click the .obj file name, and then click Insert to add the 3D content to the artboard. Alternatively, you could double-click the .obj file name.
>
> The 3D object appears on the artboard, and a Viewport3D object is created in the Objects and Timeline panel. Within the Viewport3D object are containers for the cameras and lights. A perspective camera, an ambient light, and a directional light are created by default.

[Find the original guide at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170489(v=vs.120).aspx)